# I broke this line replacing water heater tubes

Tags: buick, lesabre

[image]

I just broke this line replacing my water heater tubes is that bad?

Comment: What year is your LeSabre? What's the engine size? What is your definition of "bad"? Are you asking how hard it's going to be to replace? What do you mean by you "broke" it? Do you have any pictures of how exactly it's broke?

Comment: If you're looking for a simple answer, yes it's bad, yes it needs replaced, you can't have coolant flushing around and building up  pressure with a bad hose, 3 miles down the road you're engine will overheat and you'll be thinking darn, if I only changed that hose :)

Comment: That looks like it could be a line for the windshield washers, in which case it's not a disaster. Try running the washers and see if anything comes out of that tube when you do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the windshield washer line to me. Simply remove the broken "L" shaped fitting bring it to your local auto parts supplier and get a replacement. If you can't remove the fitting from the tube just cut the tubing at the fitting. If it looks like the tubing will be too short purchase a short length of tubing (usually sold by the foot) and 2 coupling fitting to attach the hose extensions.

Comment: Or crush the remaining plastic bits of the fitting with pliers, and fish out the pieces.  If that splits the rubber hose, you needed to replace that anyway.